# IVMRMixerControl9 not implemented on Video Mixing Renderer 9

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

I am trying to extract the `IVMRMixerControl9` from the Video Mixing Renderer 9, but this COM based Direct Show filter doesn't list this interface as implemented, and I can't `QueryInterface` for it. I am trying to set enable the "YUV mixing mode", which I presumably do using the [`IVMRMixerControl9::SetMixingPrefs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390467(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Why does MSDN documentation list the VMR9 implementing `IVMRMixerControl9`, but I can't extract the interface? I have checked on Windows XP and Windows 7, no luck.

```
var vmr9 = new VideoMixingRenderer9() as IBaseFilter;
// this is always null. this is the C# equivalent of QueryInterface
var mixerControl = vmr9 as IVMRMixerControl9;
```

Here is an image of the setting I am trying to enable.

[image: Pixture of setting trying to enable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too early, the mixer is loaded on demand. Or, you can force it by explicit `SetNumberOfStreams` call.

```
        IBaseFilter baseFilter = new VideoMixingRenderer9() as IBaseFilter;
        IVMRFilterConfig9 vmrFilterConfig = baseFilter as IVMRFilterConfig9;
        vmrFilterConfig.SetNumberOfStreams(1);
        IVMRMixerControl9 vmrMixerControl = baseFilter as IVMRMixerControl9;
        Debug.Assert(vmrMixerControl != null);
```

Comment: That was it, but for the love of God and all that is Holy, how the f*** did you know that...   Documentation?

Comment: Well it's documented, e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377377) "This value does not cause any extra pins to be created, but it does force the VMR to go into "mixer mode."", but it's more a thing that you can find when you already know the answer OR you read carefully and stumble on it accidentally some time in past. Let us say it's a known hack, and you know it too now thanks to Holy StackOverflow. And the love of God.